# MySql server is not running in XAMPP. Stuck at attempting to run MySql

Tags: mysql, xampp

When I start mysql server in xampp it's stuck at attempting to run MySql. I have tried changing port in mysql.ini (3306>3307) but it doesn't work. The information I get from mysql-error.log is as follows

```
2017-06-18 11:38:39 5920 [Note] InnoDB: Using mutexes to ref count buffer 
pool pages
2017-06-18 11:38:39 5920 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2017-06-18 11:38:39 5920 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows 
interlocked functions
2017-06-18 11:38:39 5920 [Note] InnoDB: _mm_lfence() and _mm_sfence() are 
used for memory barrier
2017-06-18 11:38:39 5920 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
2017-06-18 11:38:39 5920 [Note] InnoDB: Using generic crc32 instructions
2017-06-18 11:38:39 5920 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 
16.0M
 2017-06-18 11:38:39 5920 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer 
 pool
  2017-06-18 11:38:40 5920 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is 
 Barracuda.
2017-06-18 11:38:40 5920 [Note] InnoDB: The log sequence numbers 1835037 and 
1835037 in ibdata files do not match the log sequence number 1880429 in the 
ib_logfiles!
2017-06-18 11:38:40 5920 [Note] InnoDB: Database was not shutdown normally!
2017-06-18 11:38:40 5920 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
2017-06-18 11:38:40 5920 [Note] InnoDB: Reading tablespace information from 
the .ibd files...
2017-06-18 11:38:40 5920 [Note] InnoDB: Restoring possible half-written data 
pages 
2017-06-18 11:38:40 5920 [Note] InnoDB: from the doublewrite buffer...
  2017-06-18 11:38:41 5920 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segment(s) are 
active.
  2017-06-18 11:38:41 5920 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2017-06-18 11:38:41 5920 [Note] InnoDB:  Percona XtraDB 
  (http://www.percona.com) 5.6.34-79.1 started; log sequence number 1880429
2017-06-18 11:38:41 3380 [Note] InnoDB: Dumping buffer pool(s) not yet 
 started
2017-06-18 11:38:42 5920 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2017-06-18 11:38:42 5920 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
2017-06-18 11:38:43 5920 [Note] mysql\bin\mysqld.exe: ready for connections.
Version: '10.1.21-MariaDB'  socket: ''  port: 3307  mariadb.org binary 
distribution
```

Comment: what does it says in XAMPP ?

Comment: Have you tried connecting to the database?

Comment: `ready for connections` ? suggests it is running

Comment: @ravi It just shows "Attempting to start MySql service"  but doesn't start.

Comment: Try connecting with 127.0.0.1 and see what happens.

Comment: @NigelRen How do I do that?

Comment: It opens IIS . @NigelRen

Comment: Connecting as in a database connection - not a browser page!